# How can I calculate the average selling price of an individual item from a list of invoices when only the cumulative sum of each invoice is available?

Tags: systems-of-equations, average

A product is purchased by a company at a lower price and sold at a profit. There are 54 products and 49 invoices. The invoice consists of multiple products sold together. Each invoice has 3 to 25 products sold together in any possible combinations. A product cannot be sold more than once in a single invoice. **The data about cost/purchase price for each individual product item is available** but their individual selling price is not. We only have the final invoice amount of the combined sale.

Example:
Invoice 1: purchase_price(A + B + C) * profit_multiplier = 1000
Invoice 2: purchase_price(A + D + X + Y) * profit_multiplier = 2000
Invoice 3: purchase_price(P + Q + R + X + Y + Z) * profit_multipler  = 1500

The profit_multiplier is determined conditionally based on the total purchase_price of each invoice and is in decreasing order as the total_purchase_price goes up.

Example of conditional profit_multiplier:
if total_purchase_price < 1000 , profit_multipler = 4.2
else if total_purchase_price < 2000, profit_multiplier = 4.0
else if total_purchase_price < 5000, profit_multipler = 3.5
else profit_multiplier = 3

So, if the total_purchase_price of an invoice x is 2500, profit_multiplier = 3.5.
invoice x = 2500 * 3.5 = 7500

Question: How can we calculate the average selling price for each of the 54 product items across all 49 invoices?

Edit: The average doesn't need to be exact but just an approximation.

Comment: So, you've got $49$ equations in $54$ unknowns, right? That's five equations too few to get a solution – there will be infinitely many solutions to the system. Can you make up five more equations, based on estimating some of the values?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to do that. We just got to get the best approximation based on this.

Comment: Well, it's like you're asking, if $x+y=73$, what's the best approximation for $x$ and $y$? If you can't make sense out of that question, then how can anyone make sense out of your question?

Comment: Yes, I understand. Let me rephrase the example:  

if A, B,C ... Z are the purchase prices of a product which are given to us.   
So say,  
A = 100, B = 200, C = 300 and so on then  
Invoice 1: (A + B + C) * profit_multiplier = 1000  
Invoice 2: (A + D + X + Y) * profit_multiplier = 2000  
Invoice 3: (P + Q + R + X + Y + Z) * profit_multiplier  = 1500  

Is there a way to approximate the individual selling price of A, B, C ... Z with this available data?

Comment: So, you *know* the values of $A,B,C,\dots$, and the only unknown is the "profit_multiplier", and the profit_multiplier is the same for every transaction?

Comment: Yes, we know the values of A, B, C ....Z. Actually, we also know the profit_multiplier. It is not the same for every transaction. It is conditional based on the total purchase price of each invoice. I updated the question with more details. Sorry, I left out this information earlier.

Comment: OK. To get the selling price of an item, add up the profit_multipliers for all the invoices involving the item, divide by the number of invoices involving the item, and multiply by the purchase price of the item.

Comment: Does that seem reasonable, Raxak?

Comment: Hi Gerry, I attempted it yesterday and the values seem reasonable to me! Thank you very much! I could mark your approach as the correct answer :)

I also attempted it by using a weighted average of the purchase prices multiplied by the selling price and got the same values as your method. I assume both these methods are basically doing the same thing.

Comment: You could write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: Find the average value of the multiplier for each item**

Average_profit_multiplier = Sum(profit_multipliers for all invoices involving the item)/ Total number of invoices involving the item

**Step 2 : Multiply by the purchase price of the item**

Final_answer = Average_profit_multiplier * Purchase_price_of_the_item